# Getting PayPal Session Time-out page, but no close button - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, paypal

I am new to this technology.

Getting issue in PayPal check out express

After user stays long time on login screen and closes by pressing (X) button, user is redirected to PayPal session time out page. Here in this page there is no close button same as in login page and so user cannot go back as its iPhone device.
This makes application stuck to one screen.
Any suggestion on this issue will be really helpful.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported this issue to PayPal and they replied that this issue will be resolved soon.

Temporarily I resolved this issue by adding `NSTimer` and after 8 minutes, I am redirecting user to transaction failed screen.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using a UIWebView? You could add a NavBar to the top and give it some kind of back-button which calls

```
goBack
```

This would help to try it again.

Comment: thanks, Can you give me some code to add navigation bar on web view controller

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess. Configure "return-url". and the close button will be visible.
P.S : worked in Javascript.